# AWS EC2 instance cannot see another instance on a specific port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I have created two EC2 instances using CloudFormation - one for the Apache web-server, another one for the PostgreSQL DB. For some reason the web-server cannot telnet into the DB instance on port 5432 even though the DB instance can telnet into the web-server instance on port 80. When I check the DB instance from localhost, it is working fine and telnetting to the localhost 5432 successfully. There are two security groups for each instance:

```
 "TheWebServerSecurityGroup" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Security Group for The web-server instance",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" }
      ],
      "VpcId" : { "Ref": "TheVPC" },
      "Tags" :  [ { "Key": "Name", "Value":  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup" } ]
    }
  },
  "TheDBSecurityGroup" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Security Group for The DB instance",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "5432", "ToPort" : "5432", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" }
      ],
      "VpcId" : { "Ref": "TheVPC" },
      "Tags" :  [ { "Key": "Name", "Value":  "TheDBSecurityGroup" } ]
    }
  },
```

What might be wrong with the configuration? Any help is appreciated.

UPD: I tried adding the following inbound/outbound rules, but with that it becomes impossible to install packages via yum:

```
"TheOutboundRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
      "Properties":{
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": 0,
          "ToPort": 5432,
          "DestinationSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheDBSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          },
          "GroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          }
      }
  },
  "TheInboundRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": 0,
          "ToPort": 5432,
          "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          },
          "GroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheDBSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          }
      }
  },
```

I also tried adding just the inbound rule (without an outbound one), but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any egress for your security groups. Is the default egress unlimited? I don't use SGs with CIDR ranges very often. Suggest you edit your question to include a screenshot of both SGs ingress and egress in the console.

I prefer to use inter-security group rules for intra-AWS access rather than CIDR based. So what I would do is:

- TheWebServerSecurityGroup allows egress to TheDBSecurityGroup on port 5432
- TheDBSecurityGroup allows ingress from TheWebServerSecurityGroup on port 5432
- TheWebServerSecurityGroup allows ingress from 0.0.0.0/0 on port 443 - and I guess 80 if you need that

Rather than allowing port 22 I suggest you look at [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html). It's more secure than SSH as you effectively get SSH from the AWS console after you log in, but you don't have to open port 22. From memory the server opens port 443 to a VPC endpoint (outgoing), which relays SSH in. It's a bit fiddly to set up but if you do it with CloudFormation once you can reuse it in many situations.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Did you try what I said? It's also easier to understand console screenshots than CloudFormation, even for someone who's been writing CloudFormation for years, so if you want help please add those screenshots.